# How can I copy a chart from one sheet to remaining sheets in my workbook whilst the newly created charts take on data from the sheets it copied to?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently did a similar thing where I copied a range of data from one worksheet to all remaining worksheets. This is below.

```
Public Sub CopyData()

Dim vRange As Variant
vRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dec 1").Range("A53:F100")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 5 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("A53:F100").Value = vRange
Next i

Worksheets("Dec 1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

Worksheets("Dec 2").Select
Cells(2, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

The original sheet, "Dec 1" also takes the range of data and creates a chart. I want to copy that chart to the other sheets as well so the chart is reading from the sheet it is placed on. The code  I have for the charts only makes an exact copy of the first chart.

Comment: Perhaps do the opposite and make a template with chart ready then copy the data in and save as each time.

Answer (score 0):

This code selects **Chart 1** in sheet **Dec 1**, copies and paste in other sheets by using the for loop.

```
Public Sub CopyChart()
    ' Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Dec 1")
    
    ' Chart
    Dim xt As Object: Set xt = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    
    ' Activate chart
    xt.Activate
    
    ' Copy chart
    xt.Copy
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 5 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        ' Set chart destination
        Sheets(i).Activate
        Range("B5").Select

        ' Paste chart
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next i
    
    ' Select sheet "Dec 1"
    ws.Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```